# How to reload the tabs in jquery easyui plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I am using the jquery easyui to implement tabs. However, there is no reload function on the tabs. There is an reload example on official document, but it seems that it is just adding a reload icon instead of having an actual reload function:

```
<div title="Tab3" iconCls="icon-reload" closable="true" style="padding:20px;display:none;">
```

[image]

Therefore, how to have the actual reload function when I press the reload icon?

Here is that document , it is short and finish read in a minute
[tabs document](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tabs.php)

**Updated:**

Refresh function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tt').tabs({
        onSelect: function (title) {
            var currTab = $('#tabs').tabs('getTab', title);
            var iframe = $(currTab.panel('options').content);
            var src = iframe.attr('src');
            $('#tt').tabs('update', {
                tab: currTab, options: { content: createFrame(src)}
            });
         }
    });
});
```

Add tab will add a `icon-reload`:

```
function addTab(title, url){  
    if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)){  
        $('#tt').tabs('select', title);  
    } else {  
        var content = '<iframe scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  src="'+url+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>';  
        $('#tt').tabs('add',{  
            title:title, 
            iconCls:'icon-reload', 
            content:content, 
            closable:true
        });  
    }  
}
```

The icon in html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabs-inner">
 <span class="tabs-title tabs-closable tabs-with-icon">Create List</span>
 <span class="tabs-icon icon-reload"></span>
</a>
```

How do I use `icon-reload` to call the function to reload the tab?

[jsfiddle link added](http://jsfiddle.net/DRJGM/)

Comment: jsfiddle your codes: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: another similar post with some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634909/refresh-tab-content-on-click-in-jquery-ui-tabs

Comment: do you want to reload the content inside a tab ?

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Thanks, that is for jquery ui but not jquery easy ui, i found that act in different way

Comment: @Raminson Thanks, i provide all the relevant codes here , since there are a lot of code, i may have to filter it out before the jsfiddle works.

Comment: That icon doesn't do what you think it does. See this demo, and notice the small grey button on the first tab: http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/tabs.html That button actually does what you want, view source to see how they added it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish great i can add function  now , but the function can not fit in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refresh icon is not supposed to update the content of the tab, but you can tweak the plugin to do so.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="width:500px;height:250px;">  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.icon-reload {
    cursor: pointer;
}​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#tt').tabs({
    border: false,
    onSelect: function(title) {
        //alert(title+' is selected');  
    }
}); 

function addTab(title, url) {
    if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)) {
        $('#tt').tabs('select', title);
    } else {
        var content = 'added tab';
        $('#tt').tabs('add', {
            title: title,
            iconCls: 'icon-reload',
            content: content,
            closable: true
        });
    }
}

function myTabUpdate(index) {
    return Math.random() + ' index ' + index;
}

$(".icon-reload").live('click', function() {
    var t = $('#tt');  
    var tabs = t.tabs('tabs');  
    var tabIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();

    $('#tt').tabs('update', {
        tab: tabs[tabIndex],
        options: {
            content: myTabUpdate(tabIndex)
        }
    });
});

addTab('Tab1', 'http://google.com');
addTab('Tab2', 'http://google.com');
addTab('Tab3', 'http://google.com');​
```

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YvdjR/4/

Notice the three ressources in `ressources tab` on the left (in the jsFiddle website):

- jquery.easyui.min.js
- icon.css
- easyui.css