# how to refresh single tab in Ajax

Tags: ajax

I have created 3 tabs in Ajax. When I click on refresh in the browser, the whole document is being loaded. But I just want to load the single tab which is currently open.
How to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634909/refresh-tab-content-on-click-in-jquery-ui-tabs

Comment: Clicking on the refresh button on the browser will always reload the whole page.To refresh any particular tab add button in your page and on clicking that add JS methods to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
$('#ajax-tab').one('click', function() {
    $('#ajax-pane').load('/some/path/that/returns/our/html');
});
```

**Javascript Code**